# android reverse tethering stops

Tags: android, tethering

I am trying to get internet connection from my PC to my android phone Sony Xperia M2 Dual.
So I follow this post, 
1.http://www.wikihow.com/Reverse-Tether-an-Android-Phone

2.http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1371345
but I am facing following problem,
USB tunnel installed successfully, I grant the super user permission.
but the app failed to connect.
In gui part of the app the app stopping at the following step by telling,

```
" Android super user may ask you to accept rights. 
Check your rights and accept superuser request now if needed. !!!
wait for super user right - 25 "
```

and also from the debug panel I copied the log file for your better understanding,

```
07-06 01:06:57:696 W/I Tool version : 3.19
07-06 01:06:57:696 W/I adb.exe
07-06 01:06:57:696 W/I aapt.exe
07-06 01:06:57:814 W/I Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

07-06 01:07:01.66 A/W process (5423) :  Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=service.tracetool.SocketService.ACTION (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:501 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:501 service.tracetool.TTBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:41 

07-06 01:07:01.74 A/I  UsbThread3 : usbServerSocket : Waiting for the host to connect
07-06 01:07:01:285 W/I Wait java service
07-06 01:07:01:399 W/I waiting android server connection ... 1
07-06 01:07:01:752 W/I Waiting for connection
07-06 01:07:03:946 W/I Sending busybox21
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  UsbThread3.run() loop error. firstByte : 39 : WTOA_copyFile

07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  UsbThread3.run() loop error. lastCommand : 32 : WTOA_setGlobalVar

07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  UsbThread3.run() loop error. Exception type : class java.io.FileNotFoundException
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  UsbThread3.run() loop error. Exception message : /storage/emulated/0/busybox21: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  UsbThread3.run() loop error. Exception cause : libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  UsbThread3.run() loop error. Exception string : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/busybox21: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:418)
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  service.tracetool.Api.copy(Api.java:1471)
07-06 01:07:04.87 A/E  service.tracetool.UsbThread.copyFile(UsbThread.java:1944)
07-06 01:07:04.88 A/E  service.tracetool.UsbThread.run(UsbThread.java:316)
07-06 01:07:04.88 A/E  UsbThread3.run() -> unexpected disconnection
07-06 01:07:04.88 A/I  UsbThread3 : usbServerSocket : Waiting for the host to connect
07-06 01:07:13:641 W/D UsbThread : ReadBytes : Connection Closed Gracefully.
07-06 01:07:33:294 W/I 
07-06 01:07:33:294 W/E Connection Aborted. Restart program and try again

Server List at 07-06 01:07:35:102

DNS List
8.8.8.8[default]
8.8.4.4
```

In the android device, It says,

```
Service is running. Not connected. If the cable was unplugged, plug it. if the tool was running and previously connected, an automatic connection will be done.
```